# Multidex support issue in Appcelerator after Appcelerator studio update

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I have a project in Appcelerator android. Everything was working fine until I update Appcelerator studio yesterday. The update was for titanium SDK and SDK got updated to 7.5.1.GA, the previous SDK which was working fine was 7.5.0.GA. Now when I try to run on either SDK it fails to launch the application after Multidex log in console.

The log is as follows :

MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support

[INFO] :   MultiDex: Installing application

[INFO] :   MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.

Comment: can you try to run it with `--log-level trace` and check the output again to see if there are any errors

Comment: Getting this following log after build successful    : 
 [WARN]  zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
[INFO]  TiApplication: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
[INFO]  MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
[INFO]  MultiDex: Installing application
[INFO]  MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
[DEBUG] AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
[TRACE] updating tiapp metadata with Appcelerator Platform...
[TRACE] Uploaded tiapp metadata with Appcelerator Platform!

Comment: the multidex message shouldn't be a problem. Are you using external modules? If so please post the <modules> section (edit the first post and use the a script block so it is easier to read)

Comment: I removed all modules and tried again adding each module and found out the module causing issue is firebase analytics. Any solution how to fix this ?

Comment: you can check the repo https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-analytics/issues to see if its a know issue

Comment: I have the same issue, in my case the App runs on 7.2.1.GA, but **not on 7.3.0 nor 7.5.0.GA**